# Socket.Select() with -1 timeout not blocking at all

Tags: c#, sockets

I am making a call to Socket.Select on multiple sockets and want the whole thread to block until one (or more) of the sockets are ready. The documentation says that if you give a timeout of -1, the timeout should be infinity. Yet, it returns almost automatically.

I am using .NET 3.5. Here is my code :

```
Socket.Select(socketAVerifier, null, null, -1);

    foreach (var socketsPrets in socketAVerifier)
    {
        switch (socketsPrets.ProtocolType)
        {
            case ProtocolType.Tcp:
                AccepterConnection();
            break;
            case ProtocolType.Udp:
                EcouterBroadcast();
            break;                        
            default:
                Journal.WriteLine("Socket de protocol inconnu" +
                                     socketsPrets.ProtocolType,
                                  "Serveur", Niveaux.Grave);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to make the call to Select blocking?

Comment: Sorry for French variable names :P

Comment: Pas de problème mon ami.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemed to be bug in .NET 3.5. Bypassed by passing Int32.MaxInt

Comment: Our app was taking a bit too much CPU while idle, thanks for confirming it's not my fault this time :P

Answer (score 0):

A setting of `-1` (or `Timeout.Infinite`) is how you set it to blocking.

I've vaguely remember (so this could be misinformation) that `Select()` returns if there is an error with one of the sockets, even if you are only interested in read readyness so you may want to check if that is why and remove the failed connection from your list passed next time you call `Select()`.

Comment: As I said, -1 makes it return automatically with no socket in either the error list or the read list. I do have encountered the behavior you have explained but it does not impact the current problem.

Comment: @Gab Royer: my point was merely that you appear to be using the correct value. Out of interest, have you tried a larger value, say 10 seconds? If so, does it return immediately or after the period has elapsed?

Comment: Other values works as expexted. I've set it to Int32.MaxInt right now so that it doesn't keep on looping for nothing

Comment: @Gab Royer: Seems others have seen this and is, apparently, [fixed in .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx#CommunityContent) (comments at bottom of page) — is upgrading an option?

Comment: Upgrading is sadly not an option. It's for a school project and they require .NET 3.5.

Comment: it seems @PaulRuane link is redirected to the .Net 4.5 version. This link works: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select(v=vs.100).aspx