# What could cause code that's perfectly fine under .NET 4.5 to be CPU greedy under 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, zeromq

I'm working with [netmq](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq)'s latest pre-release and I'm finding the below program will consume virtually no CPU under .NET 4.5 yet is fixed at 13% under version 3.5 of the framework.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            using (NetMQContext context = NetMQContext.Create())
            {
                using (NetMQSocket requester = context.CreateRequestSocket()) // creating this socket seems to fix cpu consumptio at 13%.. why?
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("LOADED");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("DISPOSED SOCKET");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("DISPOSED CONTEXT");
            Console.ReadKey();
        });

        while (true) Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a potential reason for this unexpected behaviour?

**Edit:**
Confirmed this occurs in .NET 3.5 and does not occur in 4 or 4.5

Comment: have you thought that perhaps it's an issue with the actual version and or dependencies of .net 3.5 vs .net 4.5 I would actually be curious what you find when you test the difference against 3.5 vs 4.0 and 4.0 vs 4.5 maybe that will be a no brainer in regards to answering your question

Comment: @zerkms % Processor Time

Comment: @DrewR what is "Processor"? These days processors contain multiple computation units. Is it a 13% of a single core or a whole core of an 8 core CPU?

Comment: @MethodMan yes, my question was intended directly at that point. Is there some astounding difference between the frameworks that I'm unaware of? Looking at the netmq code that's being called - it's just constructors & assignments. Puzzled.

Comment: @zerkms From my understanding of the Windows OS, all cores combined. I'm working from the CPU % and CPU time figures for the process in task manager.

Comment: I couldn't answer that because I do not know everything about .net framework and what the changes are as well what has been deprecated and what has not ... etc.... Drew R makes a good point wonder if there is a difference between 32bit Windows 7 for example vs the 64Bit.. which if I am not mistaken a majority of it's core runs on .netframework

Comment: @DrewR 13% looks suspiciously similar to 100% of 1/8 cores. Any chance you provide a screenshot of a task manager with the corresponding process?

Comment: @zerkms I don't think it would tell you much beyond what I have stated.
CPU % for that process is fixed at 13%. Total CPU time is increasing steadily. No working set delta (memory activity). I check the performance tab, it shows CPU load spread more or less evenly across all 8 charts (4 cores + hyperthreading).

Comment: I think the issue is with AsyncIO (a library NetMQ is depended on), when use on dotNet3.5 it is using alternatives to concurrent queue and blocking collection. I think you will get fast answer with using a profiler (also suggest download the source code of netmq and asyncio). I will try too look into it soon (disclosure: I'm a maintainer of NetMQ and AsyncIO)

Comment: @somdoron thanks - i have an issue open for it as you know.
I'll look at the queue implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem seems to be that in .Net 3.5 there is a bug with Socket.Select.

[Socket.Select() with -1 timeout not blocking at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959542/socket-select-with-1-timeout-not-blocking-at-all)

Comment: There is a pending pull request to fix the issue: https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/pull/213